# Is it possible to implement navigation in an android app with something other than google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, directions

I am planning on adding to an android app  I made last year using Java in which I used Google maps for polylines to show direction routes. This year, I want to add real-time navigation but it seems near impossible with Google maps so I wanted to know if alternatives exist that will allow for real-time navigation

Comment: yes there are several out there. which of them have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Open Street Map. Its completely free, i used it before (a good few years back now) and it was easy to use.

https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid